# Curvature of hypersurface in flat spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, curvature

Can we have a hypersurface in flat spacetime whose curvature is non zero?
If yes, then what is the physical significance of that?

I think there can be a hypersurface in flat spacetime with non zero curvature.For example:  If hypersurface is $t-vx=constant$ which gives $dt=vdx$ then line element on hypersurface is $ds^2=dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2=(v^2 -1)dx^2- dy^2- dz^2$
calculating Riemann tensor we can find they are non zero.

Comment: well you can have curved hypersurface in 3D space, why would be spacetime different?

Comment: Ahh got it. Thanks. The question seems silly to me now.